# Web server problem in C

Tags: c

I've written a web server in c, and it can get a connection by enter http://localhost:8080/ in the web browser, but how can i go forward in the project so I can get the homepage in the browser?

The only thing which is happening now is that a connection is accepted, and nothing more! If you want to see the code, then say so!

```
main(){

        WORD wVersionRequested;
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int err, ok, clientAddrLen, serverSocket, clientSocket;
        struct addrinfo *info;
        struct sockaddr clientAddr;


        wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);


        //Creates a socket with 3 pre-defined values found in the libraries.
        serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        ok = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "8080", NULL, &info);
        if(ok!=0) {
                WCHAR * error = gai_strerror(ok);
                printf("%s\n",error);
        }


        printf("Waiting for connection...\n");


        //Binds the port to the socket.
        ok = bind(serverSocket, info->ai_addr, info->ai_addrlen); 
        if(ok == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                err = WSAGetLastError();
                printf("%d\n",err);
        }
        ok = listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if(ok == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                err = WSAGetLastError();
                printf("%d\n",err);
        }


        //Creates new socket after another IP connects.
        clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, &clientAddr, &clientAddrLen);


        printf("Connected!\n");

        //Sends a message on the new socket.
        sendMessage(clientSocket);
        printf("Message sent.\n");


        //Writes a log for the server.
        writeServerLog("127.0.0.1", " GET /HTTP1.1 C:/Server/index.html", "index.html", 100);


        getchar(); //Waiting for input, Used to stop the server before terminating.


        //Cleanup.
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
}


void sendMessage(int socket){

        string message;


        message = "<html><body>Welcome to the server!</body></html>";
        send(socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
}


void writeServerLog(string ip, string recieved, string response, int sizeOfResponse){

        FILE *log;
        SYSTEMTIME st;


        GetSystemTime(&st);
        log = fopen("serverlog.txt", "a");
        fprintf(log, "IP: %s DaTi: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d Recv: %s Resp: %s Size: %d\n", ip, st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, recieved, response, sizeOfResponse);
        fclose(log);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. **Why** are you writing your own web server?

Comment: We shouldn't have to say we want to see the code, it's expected.

Comment: Return the proper http headers, and the body of the page based on the request header sent from the browser...

Comment: What are you stuck on? Question is incredibly broad. Please refine it.

Comment: I can't redirect the homepage to the web browser through the server!

Comment: it's in the sendMessage function i have to do something so the browser can get the homepage, right?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the headers. Install firebug and look at the net tab. It will show you what a proper response should look like.

Answer (score 3):

Speak [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), or at least fake it.

Comment: This is the point, but you'd expect this to have been covered in class, or at least that the students would be told what to look for...

Answer (score 1):

When you get request from browser, this request may be

```
GET /filename.ext HTTP/1.0
Host: ...
User-agent: ...
...
```

You should search for your filename.ext

If .ext is .htm or .html

Function sendMessage should send

```
"HTTP/1.0 200 Ok\nConnection: close\nContent-type: text/html\nContent-length: 999999\n\n"
```

replace 999999 with the actual length of your file

send the content of your file

If .ext is .gif

Function sendMessage should send

```
"HTTP/1.0 200 Ok\nConnection: close\nContent-type: image/gif\nContent-length: 999999\n\n"
```

replace 999999 with the actual length of your file

send the content of your file

And so on

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the connection, you simply have to check what file the browser is asking for and send it. For example, when you first connect to a web server your browser is asking something like `GET HTTP/1.1 index` so the server has to send the main page. It just opens it, reads from it and  `send()`s it back. Then the browser will look into that page and asks again if it finds images/videos or whatever, finally it shows you the page. Give a look [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#getaddrinfo), it will surely help you. :)